# Sometimes when I click the Add button the function is adding an empty array to the JSON file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, material-ui

Sometimes when I click the Add button the function is adding an empty array to the JSON file. But sometimes it works as intended. I've tried moving the variables and state around and it is still doing the same thing. The exercise prop comes from a search of an API and the prop is passed down to this component. The component displays a list of saved exercise cards that can be added to the database. Why is this happening?

```
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  CardMedia,
  Container,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";
import React, { useState } from "react";
const ExerciseCard = ({ exercise }) => {
  const [selectedExercise, setSelectedExercise] = useState([]);
  const [selectedExerciseName, setSelectedExerciseName] = useState();
  const [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState([]);
  const addExerciseToDB = async () => {
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/savedexercises")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFetchedData(data);
        return fetchedData;
      });
    const savedFetchedName = fetchedData.map((fetched) => fetched.name);
    setSelectedExercise([]);
    setSelectedExercise({
      apiId: exercise.id,
      name: exercise.name,
      target: exercise.target,
      gifUrl: exercise.gifUrl,
    });
    setSelectedExerciseName(exercise.name);
    if (savedFetchedName.includes(selectedExerciseName)) {
      console.log("already added exercise");
    } else {
      console.log("adding new exercise");
      await fetch("http://localhost:3001/savedExercises", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(selectedExercise),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Box>
          <Card>
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt={exercise.name}
              image={exercise.gifUrl}
            />
            <CardContent sx={{ pb: 2, height: "75px" }}>
              <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ pb: 1 }}>
                {exercise.name.toUpperCase()}
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="body2">
                {exercise.target.toUpperCase()}
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <Box>
              <Box>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  color="error"
                  size="medium"
                  sx={{ m: 2 }}
                  onClick={() => addExerciseToDB()}
                >
                  Add
                </Button>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
export default ExerciseCard;
```

```
    await fetch("http://localhost:3001/savedexercises")
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFetchedData(data);
        return fetchedData;
      });
```

Comment: Although you are calling `setFetchedData(..)` the fetchedData state is not guaranteed to update immediately. You should make the fetch call. And then use the useEffect hook to watch for fetchedData value change, and then run the rest of the code in there.

Comment: @gunwin I edited the post, can you take a look and see if that is correct? it seems to be working fine, but I wanted to make sure.